# Spring batch process not executing batch related table creation script in production environment and failing but working in dev,qa,staging environment

Tags: spring-batch

We are facing a weird problem. We have written a batch JOB and it is working fine in DEV/QA/Staging environment but in production environment we are getting below error

```
20211122 00:00:47.766.[main]> [DEBUG]- c.u.j.c.EnableEncryptablePropertiesBeanFactoryPostProcessor- CID[] UID[] - Application Event 
Raised: ApplicationFailedEvent 
20211122 00:00:47.771.[main]> [ERROR]- o.s.b.SpringApplication- CID[] UID[] - Application 
startup failed 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
at org.company.xxx.etl.Etl.main(DfsEtl.java:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
**Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL 
grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? order by 
JOB_INSTANCE_ID desc]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table 
or view does not exist**
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:684)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:716)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:726)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.getJobInstances(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:230)
at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.SimpleJobExplorer.getJobInstances(SimpleJobExplorer.java:173)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.getJobInstances(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.getNextJobParameters(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:212)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:123)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:117)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732)
... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: **ORA-00942: table or view does not exist**

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:774)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:925)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4845)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1501)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:692)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
```

Then we compare logs of production and other environment and found that in other environment schema-oracle10g.sql script is executing during batch initialization but in production environment it is not happening.

DEV/QA/Staging initialization log which is not executing in production environment

```
20211122 10:17:18.509.[main]> [INFO ]- o.s.j.d.init.ScriptUtils- CID[] UID[] - Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql] 
20211122 10:17:18.573.[main]> [DEBUG]- o.s.j.d.init.ScriptUtils- CID[] UID[] - 0 returned as update count for SQL: CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE ( JOB_INSTANCE_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , VERSION NUMBER(19,0) , JOB_NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL, JOB_KEY VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL, constraint JOB_INST_UN unique (JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY) )  
20211122 10:17:18.614.[main]> [DEBUG]- o.s.j.d.init.ScriptUtils- CID[] UID[] - 0 returned as update count for SQL: CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION ( JOB_EXECUTION_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , VERSION NUMBER(19,0) , JOB_INSTANCE_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL, CREATE_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, START_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL , END_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL , STATUS VARCHAR2(10) , EXIT_CODE VARCHAR2(2500) , EXIT_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(2500) , LAST_UPDATED TIMESTAMP, JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION VARCHAR(2500) NULL, constraint JOB_INST_EXEC_FK foreign key (JOB_INSTANCE_ID) references BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID) )  
20211122 10:17:18.637.[main]> [DEBUG]- o.s.j.d.init.ScriptUtils- CID[] UID[] - 0 returned as update count for SQL: CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS ( JOB_EXECUTION_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL , TYPE_CD VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL , KEY_NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL , STRING_VAL VARCHAR2(250) , DATE_VAL TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL , LONG_VAL NUMBER(19,0) , DOUBLE_VAL NUMBER , IDENTIFYING CHAR(1) NOT NULL , constraint JOB_EXEC_PARAMS_FK foreign key (JOB_EXECUTION_ID) references BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID) )  
20211122 10:17:18.699.[main]> [DEBUG]- o.s.j.d.init.ScriptUtils- CID[] UID[] - 0 returned as update count for SQL: CREATE TABLE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION ( STEP_EXECUTION_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , VERSION NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL, STEP_NAME VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL, JOB_EXECUTION_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL, START_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL , END_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL , STATUS VARCHAR2(10) , COMMIT_COUNT NUMBER(19,0) , READ_COUNT NUMBER(19,0) , FILTER_COUNT NUMBER(19,0) , WRITE_COUNT NUMBER(19,0) , READ_SKIP_COUNT NUMBER(19,0) , WRITE_SKIP_COUNT NUMBER(19,0) , PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT NUMBER(19,0) , ROLLBACK_COUNT NUMBER(19,0) , EXIT_CODE VARCHAR2(2500) , EXIT_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(2500) , LAST_UPDATED TIMESTAMP, constraint JOB_EXEC_STEP_FK foreign key (JOB_EXECUTION_ID) references BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID) )  
20211122 10:17:18.732.[main]> [DEBUG]- o.s.j.d.init.ScriptUtils- CID[] UID[] - 0 returned as update count for SQL: CREATE TABLE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT ( STEP_EXECUTION_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, SHORT_CONTEXT VARCHAR2(2500) NOT NULL, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT CLOB , constraint STEP_EXEC_CTX_FK foreign key (STEP_EXECUTION_ID) references BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION(STEP_EXECUTION_ID) )  
20211122 10:17:18.767.[main]> [DEBUG]- o.s.j.d.init.ScriptUtils- CID[] UID[] - 0 returned as update count for SQL: CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT ( JOB_EXECUTION_ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, SHORT_CONTEXT VARCHAR2(2500) NOT NULL, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT CLOB , constraint JOB_EXEC_CTX_FK foreign key (JOB_EXECUTION_ID) references BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID) )
```

Here are some info

```
Database Version: Oracle 12C (In production we have RAC)
Spring Version: 1.5.4.RELEASE
```

Data source configuration:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@db.com:xxxx:yyy
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=user123
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical- 
strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Any help would be appreciated why is this happening or how to investigate

Comment: For Spring Boot 1.5.x, the property that initializes Spring Batch tables is `spring.batch.initializer.enabled`. According to your description, this property should be set to true in DEV/QA and false in production. Is that the case?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine we did not add this property in any environment

Comment: There should be a difference in the configuration between these environments if you see this difference in behaviour. You need to create Spring Batch [tables](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql) in the production database before running your job.